# For loop ignoring first line, after first loop execution in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, search, struct

I am trying to store some `products` in an array and further, I will insert a new product to this array or I will delete an existing from this array. It is my plan, and I am trying something like bellow.

When looping, first loop executed successfully, but from second loop only showing `Enter product name`, but `scanf("%s", p[i].pname)` not giving me to insert the value. Would someone help me to solve this!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct product{
    char pname[30];
    int quantity;
    float cost;
};
/*void insertnew();
void delete();*/
void main()
{
    struct product p[50];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       printf("Enter Product Name:\n");
       scanf("%s", p[i].pname);
       printf("Enter Quantity:\n");
       scanf("%d", &p[i].quantity);
       printf("Enter Cost:\n");
       scanf("%.2f", &p[i].cost);
       printf("*****************\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       printf("Name    = %s\n",p[i].pname);
       printf("Quantity = %d\n",p[i].quantity);
       printf("Cost = %.2f\n",p[i].cost);
       printf("-----------\n");
    }
}
/*void insertnew(){}
 void insertnew(){}*/
```

It will be more helpful for me if `insertnew()` and `delete()`, what am I going to do, is the right way?

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Note that `scanf("%.2f", &p[i].cost);` is incorrect. Try `int res = scanf("%f", &p[i].cost);` The `%.` is not a valid format specifier. Even if you do succeed in truncating to 2 decimals, anything that remains will be input into the next `scanf("%s", p[i].pname);` It isn't magically forgotten.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%s", p[i].pname);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current statement: `if( scanf("%s", p[i].pname) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for pname failed\n" ); ` perhaps followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` '}'   2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: OT: regardless of what certain compilers (like visual studio) allow, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers (3, 30, 50).  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: OT: why declare an array of 50 instances of the struct, then only use the first 3?

Comment: regarding: *It will be more helpful for me if insertnew() and delete(), what am I going to do, is the right way?* What are you asking?  Please clarify.

Comment: Strongly suggest making `struct product p[50];` into the head of a linked list (this will require adding a 'next' pointer to the struct.  Then declare the head of the list as: `struct produce *head = NULL;`  Then use dynamic memory for each entry into the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tried to compile your code with gcc, I got a warning:

```
prod.c:20:8: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ 
in format [-Wformat=]
        scanf("%.2f", &p[i].cost);
```

This drew my attention to the spurious "." in the scanf argument. Once I removed it, it compiled without warnings, and your code scanned all three items for me and printed them correctly.

Note however, that while the above will get the simple case to work, you need to perform input validation testing the return values of `scanf()` and retrying or aborting the input in case of failure - depending on what you intended to do in case of invalid input. Or - to be more robust - as was suggested in a comment by Weather Vane, read the input into a string with `fgets()` and then try to parse it with `sscanf()`.

Overall, `scanf()` is not a good fit if the input can contain invalid entries - you should build some custom solution instead.

Comment: This does not solve it. Entering the cost as `1.23` still skips the next string entry. I recommend entering each data with `fgets` into a generous string and then using `sscanf` on the string, with validation.

Comment: Using `%2f` looks for 2 characters.  If you enter `1.23`, the `scanf()` processes `1.` (as 1.00) and leaves the `23` to be interpreted as the next name.  On the whole, the width is not useful for user input; it might be useful for machine-generated, strictly formatted data.

Comment: how come `gcc` did not give you a warning about `void main()` because it does not have a return type of `int`?

Comment: OT: when compiling with `gcc`, always enable the warnings,  Suggest: `gcc -c sourceFile.c -o objectFile.o -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Comment: Also `"warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]"`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here, when you're attempting to read in a `float`:

```
scanf("%.2f", &p[i].cost);
```

Format specifiers for `scanf`, unlike those for `printf`, do not take a precision specifier.  This means the `.` character is invalid as part of a format string.

If you compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra` on gcc) it will warn you of this:

```
x1.c:20:8: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat=]
        scanf("%.2f", &p[i].cost);
        ^
```

This results in nothing being read in when you input a value for this field, and the given textis left in the input buffer.  When the next `scanf` executes expecting a string, it reads what is already in the buffer without prompting.

The correct way to handle this (at least for a `float`) is to remove any kind of length specifier:

```
scanf("%f", &p[i].cost);
```

If the user enters any more significant digits, you won't see them when you print with `%.2f`.

Answer (score 0):

cost expect to store a type float. So scan a float.
(then it can be displayed with any format)

```
scanf("%f", &p[i].cost);
```

then it works:

```
  Enter Product Name:
    boxa
    Enter Quantity:
    10
    Enter Cost:
    11.5
    *****************
    Enter Product Name:
    boxb
    Enter Quantity:
    4
    Enter Cost:
    12.4
    *****************
    Enter Product Name:
    boxc
    Enter Quantity:
    122
    Enter Cost:
    3.3
    *****************
    Name    = boxa
    Quantity = 10
    Cost = 11.50
    -----------
    Name    = boxb
    Quantity = 4
    Cost = 12.40
    -----------
    Name    = boxc
    Quantity = 122
    Cost = 3.30
    -----------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
scanf("%.2f",&p[i].cost);
```

Scanf doesn't accept the formatted float value. You can only change it while printing the value. change that line to

```
scanf("%f",&p[i].cost)
```

Everything else seems fine.